# advice on how to create a site hosted in google

Tags: html

I would like to create a website like this http://www.andperseand.se/, where it is hosted in google? Any idea of what I should look at? Or how do i create this.

Thanks

Comment: That site uses google docs not gmail

Comment: @secretformula ok. any idea on how i could go about coding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just the URL. You can change it with the CNAME via your host. For the content itself I believe its just a basic file. There's nothing more to it, its just published. Also known as "view only" I'm not sure what more there is, since it technically isn't a website hosted on Google.